# How to query the sqflite database using the LIKE statement and the % or * sql wildcard

Tags: dart, flutter, sqflite

I'm trying to query a Companies table using the companyName, I want to get the companies whose companyName(s) contains a query string, not only the companies whose companyName are exact matches of my query strings. If I was using sql, I would use the 
  ---WHERE companyName LIKE %queryString% statement.
So my question is how do I make such a query in sqflite?
Right now I am getting a syntax error because of the %

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE Companies(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
        name TEXT,
        email TEXT, 
        website TEXT, 
        about TEXT, 
        phone TEXT,
        logo TEXT,
        created_at TEXT
      );
 );
```

Code for searching

```
Future<List<CompanyModel>> filterCompanies(String filterCriteria) async {
final db =await database;
List<CompanyModel> filteredCompanies = [];

var res = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE name LIKE %?%;", [filterCriteria]);
if(res.length !=null){
  for (var item in res){
    filteredCompanies.add(JobModel.fromDb(item));
  }

 } 
 return filteredCompanies;
}
```

When I add the %, I get a syntax error.

Comment: Where is your code ? What is your db structure ? What have you found in the existing documentation that is relevant to your issue ?

Comment: The existing documentation says nothing on the subject. I found nothing on the issue when I searched for ways of doing it. I edited the post with my code

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The accepted answer leads to build error for me. I'm using sqflite: ^1.1.7+1 with flutter: v1.13.5.
From the discussion below, it comes out the percent character should be in the parameter instead of in the query, i.e.,

```
 res = await db.query(
  "Companies",
  where: "name LIKE ?"
  whereArgs: ['%$title']
 );
```

Ref: https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/316

Answer (score 11):

I tried all of the answers above but not worked. Finally:

```
await db.query(
  "Companies",
  where:  "name LIKE ?",
  whereArgs: ['%$query%']
);
```

Comment: This one is a working solution for me, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The below code works:

```dart
var res = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE name LIKE '%$filterCriteria%'");
```

Comment: I guess the answer is , you need to put % on both sides of the LIKE variable

Answer (score 3):

This is the code that ended up working perfectly for me.

```
res = await db.query(
  "Companies",
  where: "name LIKE '%$?%'"
  whereArgs: [title]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this syntax : **LIKE " searched string "**

Here is an example :

> var res = await db.rawQuery(' SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE name LIKE "%$filterCriteria%" 
>     ');

It works with flutter and sqflite

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var res = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE name LIKE '%?%';", [filterCriteria]);
```

Instead of

```
var res = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE name LIKE %?%;", [filterCriteria]);
```

put like condition in single quote('...')

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

var res = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE name LIKE ?",['%$filterCriteria%']);

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.